# Searching for multiple patterns in a string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

In t-sql my dilemma is that I have to parse a potentially long string (up to 500 characters) for any of over 230 possible values and remove them from the string for reporting purposes. These values are a column in another table and they're all upper case and 4 characters long with the exception of two that are 5 characters long.

Examples of these values are:

```
USFRI
PROME
AZCH
TXJS
NYDS
XVIV. . . . .
```

Example of string before:

```cs
"Offered to XVIV and USFRI as back ups.  No response as of yet."
```

Example of string after:

```cs
"Offered to and as back ups.  No response as of yet."
```

Pretty sure it will have to be a UDF but I'm unable to come up with anything other than stripping ALL the upper case characters out of the string with PATINDEX which is not the objective.

Comment: *remove them from the string* so what is that you're showing us as sample data?

Comment: If this is for reporting purposes, wouldn't it be easier to do this in the front-end?

Comment: Yes, Stu.  I just want to strip those out of the string for reporting.

Comment: What are your parsing requirements? It appears that you want to search for _words_, not just groups of characters. What do you expect if a string includes "... from USFRI. Otherwise they ..." where the delimiters are a space and a period? Or a comma? Quotation mark?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build a function to do the cleaning of one sentence, then call that function from your query, something like this `SELECT Col1, dbo.fn_ReplaceValue(Col1) AS cleanValue, * FROM MySentencesTable`. Your fn_ReplaceValue will be something like the code below, you could also create the table variable outside the function and pass it as parameter to speed up the process, but this way is all self contained.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_ReplaceValue(@sentence VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @allValues TABLE (rowID int, sValues VARCHAR(15))
    DECLARE @id INT = 0

    DECLARE @ReplaceVal VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @numberOfValues INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyValuesTable)

    --Populate table variable with all values
    INSERT @allValues 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY MyValuesCol) AS rowID, MyValuesCol
    FROM MyValuesTable
    
    SET @ResultVar = @sentence

    WHILE (@id <= @numberOfValues)
    BEGIN
        SET @id = @id + 1
        SET @ReplaceVal = (SELECT sValue FROM @allValues WHERE rowID = @id)

        SET @ResultVar  =  REPLACE(@ResultVar, @ReplaceVal, SPACE(0))
    END

    RETURN @ResultVar
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unavoidably cludgy but one way is to split your string into rows, once you have a set of words the rest is easy; Simply re-aggregate while ignoring the matching values*:

```
with t as (
    select 'Offered to XVIV and USFRI as back ups. No response as of yet.' s 
    union select 'Another row AZCH and TXJS words.'
), v as (
    select * from (values('USFRI'),('PROME'),('AZCH'),('TXJS'),('NYDS'),('XVIV'))v(v)
)

select t.s OriginalString, s.Removed
from t
cross apply (
    select String_Agg(j.[value], ' ') within group(order by Convert(tinyint,j.[key])) Removed
    from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(s, ' ', '","'),'"]')) j
    where not exists (select * from v where v.v = j.[value])
)s;
```

<sub>* Requires a fully-supported version of SQL Server.</sub>

Comment: The CTE `t` is the sample data, just replace it with your actual table. splitting the string into rows of words is the method I'm suggesting above - there's no technical reason why it shouldn't work on a 500 character column, the only issues would be edge-cases not shown in your example data with using a space as the delimiter.

Comment: Yes @Stu, that's basically what I want to accomplish but where you have the two hard-coded string examples unioned together I'll need to select a field containing a string that can have up to 500 characters in it. They can be actual paragraphs. Can this be done without splitting the string up into rows? –

Comment: Forgive me @Jim I'm not sure I understand, you're basically repeating the now deleted comment from above, my comment above stands. My suggestion is to split the data into words - why don't you try it on your real data? The alternative is some complicated string manipulation - someone may offer a solution like that but I suspect it would require a recursive CTE to repeatedly amend the source data, not a route I'd personally use.

Comment: by edge-cases do you mean instances where there may not be a space between a code and another character?  Cases with the following are common:

'Customer declines: IIAM- put it on hold; TXJS- no active protocols; Prom- age'

Sorry for repeating the deleted comment.  This is my first time posting here so I'm navigating uncharted waters.

Comment: Basically yes I mean exactly that; your sample data shows the strings you need to find and remove are nicely delimited with spaces, but that's probably not always the case, and some additional handling of those edge cases would be required. Exactly what that would be - probably the cliche "exercise for the reader" applies :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a table (either temporary or permanent), and loading these 230 string values into this table.  Then use it in the following delete:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE col IN (SELECT col FROM tempTable);
```

If you just want to *view* your data sans these values, then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM tempTable);
```

Comment: I don't want to alter the contents in the column.  This is strictly for reporting purposes.

Comment: @Jim Then use a select query, q.v. my updated answer.